# Writing a tuple in file in erlang

Tags: file, erlang, ejabberd

How to write a tuple in file in erlang.What i have tried so far is

```
Result={1,"OK",3},
file:write_file("/tmp/logs.txt", Result, [append])
```

But it is giving bad args error.
Any solutions??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file:write_file` takes an iolist, not a plain Erlang term.  You could format the term as an iolist using `io_lib:format`:

```
file:write_file("/tmp/logs.txt", io_lib:format("~p.~n", [Result]), [append])
```